# "ExceptionChangeExtension" or extension_exceptionchangeextension

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to setup up alerts for Application Insights
Smart Detection following this

https://sway.office.com/oxuf7sCHqKD3BubJ and in the step 3 custom search query they have used

```
systemEvents
| where name == "ProactiveDetectionInsight"
| where tostring(dimensions.InsightDetectionType) == "ExceptionChangeExtension"
```

but as per Microsoft
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/proactive-arm-config internal name is different "extension_exceptionchangeextension" which one should I use please help.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please help mark it as an answer. It would help others. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The doc(https://sway.office.com/oxuf7sCHqKD3BubJ) is correct, you should use "ExceptionChangeExtension".

You can just have a test in the application insights [Analytics playground](https://analytics.applicationinsights.io/demo#/discover/query/main):

when query with "ExceptionChangeExtension", it can return some results.

when query with "extension_exceptionchangeextension", it has no results return.

screenshot as below:

[image]

Also you can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24264#issuecomment-460547744) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set manual alert for the abnormal rise in exception category(failure Anomalies). You can follow these steps for setting alert on smart detection-

Step 1:- Browse to your application insight in Azure portal.
Step 2- Click on the  Smart Detection settings
 [image]

Step 3- Enable the alert for Failure Anomalies.
Step 4- Provide the intended recipient in the list for mailer.

then good to proceed with smart detection alert.

You will get an alert mailer like below-

[image]